# How to apply "direct georeferencing" with PTZ camera?

Tags: python, georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, ocean

I have images taken from Mavic 2 drone over the ocean,

and the images have been taken with the orientation angle (roll, yaw, pitch) of both drone and gimbal.

With these tilted environment, I want to generate "orthorectified" image.

Could you advice some simple formula for calculation?

Or open source code for conducting direct georeferencing?

At first, I tried to perform "Vertical Photo Placer", but this tool only consider the flight yaw degree. Thus, I wonder if there exists any other open source code.

Comment: You can read the XMP and EXIF data from a DJI Drone image with the python PIL.   There is also Open Drone Map - https://www.opendronemap.org/webodm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vertical photo placer will use the camera GNSS location at the time of capture, plus the WGS84 elevation, and the azimuth to roughly create a footprint on the land.  This tool is a great start for further georeferencing but not the tool for you.

Several photogrammetry softwares like WebODM (feeware), Agisoft Metashape, and DroneDeploy will allow you to generate a single orthomosaic from your drone imagery but these tools are dependent on sufficient overlap and image correspondence.  Your ocean imagery is not likely going to process in these softwares but it is worth the free trial to give it a go.

For automating the georeferencing processes using the image metadata (pitch, roll, yaw, elevation) you can [read this post here](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop).  Disclosure - I am the coder for this project.